# Вывод список стран из ВК АПИ

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Всем доброго времени суток.
Пытаюсь вывести страны ВК,но выдает ошибку.
1. index.php(точка входа)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2.models/vk.php
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3.controllers/controller_vk.php
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4.views/view_vk.ph
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но,выдает кучу ошибок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Запрос работает,если выводить через обычный echo.
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

UPD:
var_dump($countries)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Обычный вывод через echo
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите структуру объекта countries,что то мне подсказывает что вы не правильно обращаетесь к объекту

Comment: @quaresma89 обновил,посмотрите,пожалуйста.

Comment: Видимо у вас в конфиге отключена возможность использования такого синтаксиса <?= ,тоже часто сталкивался с подобной проблемой.Всегда использую echo и читабельнее и понятнее

Comment: Попробуйте использовать вместо шорт тегов <? полное объвление <?php

Comment: уже выводил таким синтаксисом,так что включен он.
добавил везде <?PHP ?> при открытие,заработало,странное это все :С
Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @quaresma89 да,так же подумал,благодарю)
Отпишите в ответах,пожалуйста,чтобы я закрыл топик.

Comment: @quaresma89 короткий синтаксис `echo` **всегда** доступен с версии >= 5.4, не зависимо от настроек в ini файле по дефолту. ...... в версиях ниже нужно крутить php.ini ........ а вот короткий синтаксис начала PHP кода `<?` по умолчанию может быть отключен, в особенности на хостингах.  Так что банально надо смотреть версию PHP и не боятся `<?=` если версия позволяет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте полное объявление начала `php` скрипта `<?php` вместо шорт тега `<?`